# how do you extract date from the file name in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have to read files in a directory and extract the dates from the file names.

```
filenames <- list.files(path="C:/Downloads/vmstat", pattern="*vmstat*", full.names=TRUE)
```

filenames like this:

```
C:/Downloads/vmstat/vmstat.2016.11.22.Tue
```

I need to extract `2016.11.22` from this filename and assign it to a variable like `dat`. How could I extract the date from the filenames?

Comment: `stringr::str_extract(filenames, "[0-9]{4}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{4}")`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match the substring that are not date and replace it with blanks (`""`)

```
gsub("^[^0-9]+\\.|\\.[A-Za-z]+$", "", filenames)
#[1] "2016.11.22"
```

Or extract the `basename` and then convert to `Date` class with `lubridate`

```
lubridate::ymd(basename(filenames))
#[1] "2016-11-22"
```

#### data

```
filenames <- "C:/Downloads/vmstat/vmstat.2016.11.22.Tue"
```

Comment: no, I need to extract the date "2016.11.22" from the file name.

Comment: @user1471980  That is what is extracted